# How to make a post page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have been searching on google but unable to find any proper tutorial. Can anyone tell me how do i make my own post page in wordpress?

For Example:

In wp-admin, There is already a Post option in menu..

```
Post>Add New

Post>All

Post>Categories

Post>Tags
```

In Add New, There is a blog form, where we can add post but I want another option in Menu.. called Licenses, Then option of Add New, When i click on it, There will be a form, What I have to do is to add Featured image in it and add title of it and publish and then it should show on license page. [Demo License](http://www.jmsmanpower.com/license.html)

Similarly I want another Trades, in which I should add trades and it should show on trades pages. Note, the trade page and license page will have different Style for showing, different Css. In Trade page there will be a boostrap accordion which will show trades, [Demo Trades](http://www.jmsmanpower.com/trades.html)

Similarly I want another page for this affiliation page.. [Demo Aff](http://www.jmsmanpower.com/affiliations.html) IN this page, there are some images with title, and sometimes client send more images, so i want a form in my wp-admin where i can just upload image and show on page like im showing. It will show differently for all pages.

How will i achieve this? Any suggestions? Any other method? im totally new to wordpress

Comment: Depending on what you want (it isn't really clear) I guess you are either looking for a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/custom_post_type) or how to add a [Meta Box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) to your edit post screen.

Comment: I have updated my question, can u check with the demo links, im converting my static website to wordpress

Comment: do you want to create custom post type like post type in wordpress?

Comment: Yes I want custom post type for license page, trade page and affiliation pages.

Comment: I think you mix up custom post type and page templates.

Comment: Sounds like you need to look at [Custom Post Types.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) You should also look at [Generate WP](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) as it has a UI for registering post types which makes it very quick. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own page template. [Here is the reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

In your template directory create a new file like `page-anyhing.php`

Add this to your start of the file:

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Template Name: Anything
  *
  * @package WordPress
 */
```

Then, when you create  a new post, at the right side of the dashboard, you can select the `Anything` from `Page Template` menu.

You need to build your page template by PHP and HTML codes.

**UPDATE**

Based on OP comment:

You need to create a new template, eg. affiliates as I mentioned above.

When you get a new affiliate, then you can create a post, and add Category: Affiliates.

In your page template you need to get posts by categories:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'affiliates' ) );
```

Here is the [reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) from `WP_Query`.

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li><h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2><div>Show image here</div></li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo "Sorry, no affiliates...";
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Im just confused, Here is the website that im converting to wordpress `http://www.jmsmanpower.com/index.html` I have converted index, about page so far. So Now i want to convert for example Affiliation page, Affiliation page has many images, sometimes client sent more images, if he send 1 image, i want to add new affiliation with title and publish. bcoz this page showing only images with title. Similarly i want for trade pages, which is showing only textual data not images. so im confused how to do it